# Django: cannot connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, django, windows

I am new to Django and I try to follow the official tutorial. since I want to connect to mysql (installed on my computer, and i checked mysql module does exit in python command line), I set the ENGINE in setting.py to be django.db.backends.mysql . and then I tried to run

```
    python manage.py syncdb
```

then I got error message like this:

```
   Error loading MySQLdb module
```

and I cannot run

```
   pip install mysql-python
```

the error msg is:

```
   Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

so what is this error? and honestly I am not sure about the difference between mysql-python and mysql-connector-python. Since i tried with "pip install mysql-connector-python" and it tells me that requirement already satisfied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the [windows binary installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) for the MySQL drivers for Python. Installing from source will not work since you do not have the development headers in Windows.

Comment: i believe i have installed the right thing. just want to ask you then what do you mean by saying that "i do not have the development headers"? what is the error thrown by pip?

Comment: When pip installs the mysql for python drivers; it downloads the source and then builds it against the MySQL client libraries. To do that it needs to have the source for MySQL client installed; and the appropriate build environment ready as well. On Windows this is very difficult to setup which is why there are the compiled binaries available.

You have attempted to install the compiled version; which has not been successful - that's why you are unable to import the library. If you install the binary version I linked; you'll be able to import without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the mysql python connector

sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Comment: well, i am not sure if I get your point or not. "pip install mysql-python" does not work with the error above. "pip install mysql-connector-python" i got "requirement already satisfied"... and one more thing, i am not running on Linux or Mac

Comment: plus, pip does not recognize this "python-mysqldb". maybe i will try on my ubuntu later.